# Install GStreamer plugins on Android

Tags: android, c++, gstreamer

I am trying to build my application on android. I am bit stucked on

```
GstElement* pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("rtspsrc location=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov ! decodebin ! appsink name=sink", &err);
```

because, `GError *err` writes out `no element "rtspsrc"`. I have already searched for some ways to add missing plugins/elements, but with no success.

I have found [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/missing-plugins.html) page, which shows how to install plugins in code, but when I tried, `gst_install_plugins_sync` returned `GST_INSTALL_PLUGINS_HELPER_MISSING` and from this point, i don't know how to continue.

I have fully built library for `gstreamer-1.0` including `libgstrtsp-1.0`, but I don't understand  why my program doesn't find it.

How can I add plugins/elements to android?

Thanks for your help!

//EDIT:

[Link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html), which I used to build libary, and I am using Android 4.4.4

Comment: I am not familiar with Android as such, but  if you have a terminal, first try using the commands `gst-launch`- to test pipeline and `gst-inspect`- to analyse elements in system. Also add the Android version, the source from where you built the GStreamer for better understanding of the question.

Comment: @vk_gst Android don't have terminal + I am doing cross-development -> developing on Ubuntu (plugins on ubuntu works)

Comment: Can you ssh onto the device that's running Android and run these commands?

Comment: @vk_gst Unfortunally, no, I already tried "Termux" application, but it seems android is too old

Comment: Have a look [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/for-android-development.html).

Comment: @vk_gst I am using QtCreator, there is no `Android.mk` file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define extra plugins inside your Android.mk file:

```
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS_RESTRICTED) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)
```

The list of available plugins groups are defined in:
*$(GSTREAMER_ROOT_ANDROID)/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/plugins.mk*

Additonally use playbin to play the RTSP stream like:

```
gst_parse_launch("playbin uri=rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov", &error);
```

Comment: I have already solved it, but yes, you are right, basicly that was my problem. Thank you!